# Keep getting 404 errors with django 2.2

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am following this tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/

and I am getting 404 errors when I try the first test saying it cannot find "polls/" below is some of my code
in mysite/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

in polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

I tried searching but I can't find anything for django 2.2

Below is a screenshot of the error message

[image: Here is a screenshot of the error message]

Comment: What is the full **exact** address you try to access in your URL-bar? For instance, is it `http://localhost:8000/polls/` or something else?

Comment: Please show the *full* error message, which should say which URLs patterns Django did try. Make sure you are editing the correct `mysite/urls.py`. It should be in the same directory as `settings.py`, not `manage.py`.

Comment: I made an edit with a screenshot of the error message,so you guys could see it

Comment: The screenshot shows `/polls` but your included URL path is `/polls/` so depending on your settings that might show a clue. Make sure there is a `/` on the end of the URL. The setting defaults to `True` but it's worth a try; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#append-slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was my directory structure. it was `mysite/urls.py` when it should've been `mysite/mysite/urls.py` in the directory with settings.py not in the directory with manage.py